# Why I don't see my log in the console at CloudWatch and lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have lambda function, but I don't see my log at the console.log in CloudWatch. what is missing here?

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    
    //Get contents of response
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    const headers = response.headers;

//Set new headers 
 headers['strict-transport-security'] = [{key: 'Strict-Transport-Security', value: 'max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload'}]; 
 headers['content-security-policy'] = [{key: 'Content-Security-Policy', value: "default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; object-src 'none'"}]; 
 headers['x-content-type-options'] = [{key: 'X-Content-Type-Options', value: 'nosniff'}]; 
 headers['x-frame-options'] = [{key: 'X-Frame-Options', value: 'DENY'}]; 
 headers['x-xss-protection'] = [{key: 'X-XSS-Protection', value: '1; mode=block'}]; 
 headers['referrer-policy'] = [{key: 'Referrer-Policy', value: 'same-origin'}]; 
 
 console.log('in handler');
 
 console.log({ xx: event.Records[0].cf.request.uri });
    
 console.log('end handler ');
 
    //Return modified response
    callback(null, response);
};
```

https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1
[image]

[image]

CloudWatch:
[image]

Lambda Test:

[image]

Comment: Are these logs from the Lambda@Edge running or from you testing in the console?

Comment: In the cloudwatch I see logs - when the function start and complete. but I don't see "in handler", or "end handler"

Comment: Sure, so is this also reproducible when you test the function in the console?

Comment: This will be based on the test event you're using to trigger the request. In the upper right of the screen you need to select the test event.

Comment: I add request to the test. but still in the log output seems okay, but in the cloudwatch is not exist

Comment: Is this the CloudWatch output for the deployed Lambda@Edge? If you've made changes since originally deployed to add these lines you would need to deploy with a new version. I added instructions in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

From the behaviour you're experiencing I suspect this is simply that a new version of the Lambda@Edge has not been deployed to the CloudFront distribution.

Whenever you need to release an update of the code you must create a new version of the Lambda function and then replace the Lambda event in your CloudFront distribution to use the new version record.

Once this happens it will take a short while to modify in every edge location so you might not immediately see these debug lines in your logs.

As this process takes time to deploy, make sure to make use of the test events (as input to your Lambda) to test the scenarios that need to be tested once the Lambda is deployed. Once you're happy with it perform the new version and deploy.

For more information take a look at the [Editing a Lambda Function for Lambda@Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-edit-function.html) page.